# Linux identifies identical .py files as different

Tags: python, linux, windows

I'm developing CGI scripts in Python. I had a basic "Hello World" script running on my server, which worked fine, but everything I tried writing on my Windows laptop (in Sublime text 2) and copying over threw Apache 500 errors, with no debugging info whatsoever. Finally, I copied the text of my HelloWorld script over to windows, pasted it into a .py file, then copied that back over, only to find that it still didn't work. I thought it might have been a permissions error, but the two files have exactly the same permissions. In nano, they look exactly the same, but one works and one doesn't. I discovered that there's something different about them by using `sdiff`, which said that they were completely different files, even though all the text was the same. I tried a hex dump and found that though the text was the same, the 1's and 0's were different. Does anyone know if there's some sort of encoding I can set in python to keep Apache from throwing errors?

Screenshot of my terminal showing the files side by side and a hex dump. test.py is the linux CGI script that works properly. **Orig.py is the script that I copied over from windows.** copied.py is a copy of test.py that I made to demonstrate what the output of `sdiff` should be when the two files are identical.

[image]

Update: Checked the encoding, both files output 
`text/x-java; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: line endings? Windows uses `\n\r` while linux uses `\n`, although I never had problems for this. By the way: images are pretty useless. Can't you copy-paste the text from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a line-endings difference, as Bakuriu mentions.

Note in the hex output:

The 'test.py' file ends with `...0a` where the 'orig.py' file ends with `...0d0a`.

`0a` corresponds to a newline `\n`, while `0d` corresponds to a linefeed `\r'.

If you open 'orig.py' in Vim, you should see `^M` at the ends of the lines.
Welcome to cross-platform development fun and games (:

You can use a program like `dos2unix` to fix this issue.